# Corners of window become black instead of transparent after using ' border-radius' in GTK-3 app

Tags: c++, css, gtk, gtkmm, cornerradius

I am trying to create GTK-3 app with round corners and I am trying to use CSS 'border-radius' property for it.
But border corners become black. What is the reason and how to fix it ?

Here is C++ code in file "main.cc":

```
#include <gtkmm/application.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example");

  Gtk::Window window;
  window.set_default_size(200, 200);

  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> css_provider = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::StyleContext> styleContext = Gtk::StyleContext::create();

  try
  {
      css_provider->load_from_path("styles.css");
  }
  catch (/*Exeption &e*/...)
  {
      std::cout << "exeption " << std::endl;
  }

  styleContext->add_provider_for_screen(Gdk::Screen::get_default(), css_provider, GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER);

  return app->run(window);
}
```

here is CSS code in file "styles.css" :

```
window
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: none;
  background-color : red;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Compiled with

```
 g++ `pkg-config --cflags gtkmm-3.0` -o exampl main.cc `pkg-config --libs gtkmm-3.0`
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

End here is result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OvV1.png
I expect that corners should be transparent, no black!

Please, help!

Answer (score 1):

The decorations of your screenshot are drawn by the window manager: there is not much you can do at application level to change that. So the short answer is "impossible".

Anyway you can circumnvent it if you are using [client-side decorations](https://askubuntu.com/questions/780359/how-can-i-enable-the-gtk3-header-bars-on-ubuntu-16-04). Take a look at the corners of the following screenshot:

[image]

I just picked up a random application using GTK3 with client-side decorations and added the following CSS fragment:

```
headerbar {
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}
window {
  border-radius: 0 0 30px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your answer! Can you give more details? Where did you take that application with client-side decorations? I am really new in all these GTK stuff :(

Comment: This is an application I wrote for an industrial machinery. It is not really important which application you choose but it is fundamental that it is using client-side decoration. See the link provided in the answer if you don't have client-side decorations enabled in your distro.

Comment: Hello again :) I have tested it on my home test PC (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS), I tried "export GTK_CSD=1" and it starts work well. How it looks now: https://imgur.com/hJxJels . But there are few problems: 1) I've changed "window" to "GtkWindow" in CSS file. I don't know why, but just "window" doesn't work on this PC. 2) When I tried to test this solution on other Ubuntu PC it doesn't work. I tried "export GTK_CSD=1" but it doesn't helps. Both computers are Ubuntu. Version: 18.04.3 LTS and 16.04.3 LTS. Maybe I missed something and I have to install some additional packages? and why "GtkWindow"?

Comment: What you are showing in the image does not look right to me: in client-side decorations the frame around the window (the title-bar included) should not be drawn by the window manager. Try to launch `gtk3-demo`: if the window manager still draw that default title bar it means it just refuses to honor client-side decorations and there is no much you can do.

Answer (score 0):

In your css you set the border to 1px solid black, shouldn't it be 1px transparent?

Comment: I tried to use "border: 1px transparent;" but it doesn't work